# Odd ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException inside Network ObjectOutputStream

Tags: java, sockets

I have a client that keeps sending messages to a server. Eventually I'm getting a `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` inside of its `writeObject` which I'm unable to understand:

```
Exception in thread "Core" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 256 out of bounds for length 256
        at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream$BlockDataOutputStream.writeBytes(ObjectOutputStream.java:1996)
        at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream$BlockDataOutputStream.writeUTF(ObjectOutputStream.java:2174)
        at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeString(ObjectOutputStream.java:1307)
        at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1173)
        at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:349)
        at ws.hikari.md5.ui.network.Client.sendStatusMessage(Client.java:64)
        at ws.hikari.md5.Core.run(Core.java:96)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
```

Here's `ws.hikari.md5.ui.network.Client.sendStatusMessage()`, it's called by Core to send the message to server.

```
public class Client implements Runnable {
// ...

    protected ObjectOutputStream oos = null;

    public boolean connect(){
        
        try{
            socket = new Socket(
                // host IP,
                // host port
            );
            oos = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
        
        }catch(IOException ex){
            logger.log(Level.FINER,"Client connect failed",ex);
            return false;
        }
        
        return true;
    }

    protected boolean sendStatusMessage(Message msg){
        if(null==socket || null==oos){
            connect();
            return false;
        }
        
    
        GsonBuilder builder = new GsonBuilder();
        builder.setPrettyPrinting().serializeNulls();
        Gson gson = builder.create();
        
        String serializedMsg = gson.toJson(msg);
        
        try{
            oos.writeObject(serializedMsg); // line 64
        }catch(SocketException ex){
            // just silence it, it's ok if Remote GUI server is offline
            connect();
            return false;
        }catch(IOException ex){
            logger.throwing("Client", "sendStatusMessage", ex);

            connect();
            return false;
        }
        
        return true;
    }
    
// ...
}
```

Comment: What version of Java are you using?

Comment: Not related to your actual problem, but why are you using `ObjectOutputStream` for this? You're serializing using GSON to JSON, and then serializing again using Java's serialization. Choose one serialization mechanism.

Answer (score 2):

You're writing to the same `ObjectOutputStream` from multiple threads simultaneously. This is not supported.

SOURCE: A small fraction of the source of `java.io.ObjectOutputStream`:

```
                int n = Math.min(csize - cpos, MAX_BLOCK_SIZE - pos);
                int stop = pos + n;
                while (pos < stop) {
                    buf[pos++] = (byte) cbuf[cpos++];
                }
```

where `pos` is a field of the BlockDataOutputStream instance associated with the OOS; various write methods affect it, and if it is modified in between these 2 lines, `cbuf` (which is hardcoded to be 256 large, vs `buf`, which is hardcoded to be 1024, therefore the error that is occurring is because `cpos` is 256, and thus `cbuf[cpos++]` is the AIOOBEx-causing line, not `buf[pos++]`, which is because `stop` is too large, which is because `pos`  got modified in between line 1 (`int n =...`) and line 2.

You can't change the source of ObjectOutputStream, and in any case this 'crash' is not its fault, its spec, like most OutputStreams, are clear that trying to write to them from multiple threads leads to utter chaos.